# htaccess url masking

Tags: .htaccess, url, masking

Hey im a total niewbie with htaccess.
On my site (mysite.com) i got a link that directs and sends variable to a page on a secure site (othersite.com/somepage.php?urlink='www.mysite.com').

How can I edit my htaccess file to rewrite othersite.com/somepage.php?urlink='www.mysite.com' to whatever value urlink has.

I have this in my htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymlinks<br>
Options All -Indexes<br>
Options Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^&urlink=(.*) http://$1 [P]
```

Answer (score -1):

Curious. Think it won't work that way; if you request a page on an other server, your own htaccess won't provide you the solution. (if you have access / own the othersite.com yourself, their htaccess could do it).

Instead, i would write a small PHP-File redirecting to otherside.com using an HTTP_HEADER.
Therefore, you could tell your htaccess to hide your php-Url.

Did I understand your question the right way?

```
<?php
$myInputURL = $my_POSTURL;
$myOtherSite = "http://www.otherside.com?urllink=";
$myURL = $myOtherSite . $myInputURL;
header("Location: ".$myURL);
?>
```

Comment: I do have access to othersite.com. the htaccess I provided is located on othersite.com.

Answer (score -1):

RewriteRule DOES NOT WORK with query string directly like that.

For example, if URL is `http://www.example.com/kitten.php?say=meow`, then RewriteRule can only match `kitten.php` part. Everything else can be matched via RewriteCond, for example: `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^urlink=(.*)`.

Please see documentation: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond

---

In your case it can be something like this (sorry, I do not know what exactly you are trying to achieve, therefore I'm just editing your existing rule):

```
Options Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^urlink=(.+)$
RewriteRule ^somepage\.php$ http://%1 [P]
```

Comment: thanks for the help guys. this is what i want to do. whenever the page https://www.amazingbiz.co.za/eshop/shopping/cart_view.php?code=e618&urlink="www.mysite.com" is shown then it must show www.mysite.com in the address bar

Comment: no. I have a product page on http://www.mysite.com but to view the cart you have to go to https://www.amazingbiz.co.za/eshop/shopping/cart_view.php?code=e618&urlink=www.mysite.com. what  i want is for the cart page url to display the product page's url like http://www.mysite.com/view_cart.php. Looks asif its impossible to do

Comment: In this case you have to do **other way around**: when user goes to `www.mysite.com/view_cart.php` you display content of `amazingbiz.co.za/eshop/...` -- that is the way of how to keep your desired `www.mysite.com` in address bar. You may try doing this with Reverse Proxy (search more for this) .. or fetch content of that `amazingbiz.co.za/eshop/...` in your PHP script (use `curl_*` functions) and display as your own page. You really have to test it -- I do not think this will be very easy to implement.